# How to call Woocommerce custom shipping class calculate_shipping method using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Based on [WooCommerce Documentation - Shipping Method API](https://woo.com/document/shipping-method-api/) tutorial, I have built a WooCommerce shipping plugin.

This is a simplified version:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function your_shipping_method_init() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
            class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
                /**
                 * Constructor for your shipping class
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct() {
                    // constructor stuff goes here
                }

                public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
                    $rate = array(
                        'label' => $this->title,
                        'cost' => '10.99',
                        'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                    );

                    // Register the rate
                    $this->add_rate( $rate );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init' );

    function add_your_shipping_method( $methods ) {
        $methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method' );
}
```

I want to call the calculate_shipping method when the user changes the option in a Select field. I am trying to call the calculate_shipping method using AJAX.

This is currently returning a 400 error.

(I also tried 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method->call_calculate_shipping').

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery('select[name="shipping_delivery_method"]').change(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'https://garpenstaging.wpenginepowered.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
                data: {
                    action: 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method::call_calculate_shipping',
                },
                success: function (output) {
                    console.log(output);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Your question need to be more detailed regarding the context, and the provided code is not testable, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec. I have changed my approach in the question and believe that the example is reproducible.

Comment: Your code is still not reproducible, as we don't have the code for your custom select field (shipping_delivery_method) where we can choose the shipping method, and we don't have any context… Where is that field located, for what purpose? What other shipping methods are enabled? … I think that you need, at least, to build/add your own custom PHP Ajax receiver function to set the chosen shipping method in WC Session and trigger `WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping()`…